# Convert tzdata into other formats?

Tags: json, timezone, converters

Back before the whole [Olson database lawsuit debacle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database#2011_lawsuit), there was a source of timezone data that provided alternate formats (e.g. XML, JSON, CSV, etc.) that was hosted on googlecode (dead link: http://code.google.com/p/tzdata/).

Now that the lawsuit threat is past, this site is no longer operational.  Fine, we can still access the [raw data at IANA](http://www.iana.org/time-zones).  However, I have been unable to find any help with ways to convert the raw data into these other formats that were previously provided by the now defunct project on googlecode.

Has anyone else found / re-created this?  I am most particularly interested in converting to JSON format.  I know I could re-build this myself, but I was hoping to avoid reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go: https://gitorious.org/tz/tzdata.

Comment: Does that repo actually have the source code that converts the raw timezone data into the different formats?  I can't find it in there.  What I am really looking for is a way to do the same conversions, but with recent data.  Something that I could automate; e.g. whenever I build my application, pull the latest timezone data from IANA and run it through some conversion tool to get the format I need.

Comment: Nope, seems that the source code for generation is missing. I just needed some data, not necessarily super up-to-date, so I didn't dig that deep. Shame :/